# "configure: error: libnl and libnl-genl are required but were not found"

Tags: linux, debian

I'm trying to configure powertop-2.5 but when I run ./configure I get a "configure: error: libnl and libnl-genl are required but were not found" error

I've run

```
sudo apt-get install libtool autoconf libnl-dev ncurses-dev pciutils-dev build-essential -y
```

as was recommended by [these guys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291904/missed-power-est-column-in-powertop) but I get the same error.

I ran

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-genl-3-dev
```

Which replaced the previous libnl file but I still get the config error.

According to [this](https://lists.01.org/pipermail/powertop/2012-November/000611.html), powertop has (or had) problems with detecting libnl but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I'm currently running Linux *username* 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" my problem by installing powertop-2.0 instead.

Answer (score 13):

I see you tried libnl-dev, maybe try libnl-3-dev instead:

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev
```

Comment: Worked for me after installing both and then running `./configure` again.

Comment: I tried ```sudo yum install libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev``` on Centos 7, but didn't resolve my issue. Are there any other ways to solve it? @kao @BeeOnRope

Comment: @Nagmat - no idea, sorry.

Comment: It worked out after executing ``` yum install libnl3-devel ```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem is the lack of the **pkg-config** application in your system (which is used to find the proper dependencies with the *configure* script). I just have the same problem in a fresh installed Ubuntu 14.04 system, and after installing the pkg-config package the *configure* script finalized successfully its work. Then I could compile and install the last version (2.6.1) of powertop.

Answer (score -2):

The use of pkg-config made the trick. I was able to install Powertop 2.7.